# "cannot find symbol" when compiling with Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, build-automation, compilation

I need to generate an apk file using an Ant script, but I'm having problems with the compile target. To automatically generate the Ant script, I've used the Android tool with the command `android update project`. The problem is that this project depends on another project, so I need to use a custom compile task.

For that reason, I've overridden that target: I've copied the compiled task from `ant_rules_r3.xml` and I've changed the `javac` task like this (see comments for what I changed):

```
<!--I've changed the target 1.5 to target 1.6 -->
<javac encoding="UTF8" target="1.6" debug="true" extdirs=""
      destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
      bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
      verbose="${verbose}"
      classpath="${extensible.classpath}"
      classpathref="android.libraries.jars">
    <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
    <!--My project has two src directories -->
    <src path="${source2.absolute.dir}" />
    <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
    <src refid="android.libraries.src" />
    <!--I've added here the src dir of the other project -->    
    <src path="${dep1.source.absolute.dir}"/>
    <classpath>
        <!--I've added here the lib dir of the other project -->
        <fileset dir="${dep1.external.libs.absolute.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${external.libs.absolute.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${extensible.libs.classpath}" includes="*.jar" />
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

The problem is that when I compile with `ant compile`, I get the following error:

```
[javac].... cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : constructor IOException(java.lang.String,java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException)
[javac] location: class java.io.IOException
[javac]             throw new IOException("Algorithm not found", e);
```

It seems as though it's been compiled with JDK 1.5 instead of 1.6 even though I have set the target property to 1.6. My computer is using Java version 1.6.0_20.

I've tried using `javac compiler="javac1.6"`, but I get the same error.

I've also set in my `build.properties`:

```
ant.build.javac.target=1.6
ant.build.javac.source=1.6
```

but it doesn't solve the problem either. Setting it to 1.3 instead of 1.6 causes more errors, so it seems it is using the JDK I'm setting here.

How can I get this to compile correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've specified the bootclasspath to use the Android SDK classes, these will probably be the ones that contain the IOException class that does not implement the two-arg constructor with a Throwable second arg.  That constructor was new in Java 6, but according to [recent Android (2.2) docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html), the Android version only has Java-1.5 style constructors, and *doesn't* implement the two newer constructors that take Throwable args.

You didn't mention whether you'd got this to build successfully before bringing in the second project - so I'd recommend checking your local Android boot classes to see what constructors IOException offers.